# Protocol Relative URLs in Drupal 6

Tags: 6

I'm trying to avoid serving pages that load css and js resources through URLs that specify either http or https.

Because Drupal is specifying http:// for the href for all the CSS and JS files.
Caching server varnish, caching the JS & CSS files twice (through http & https).

Instead of

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/css/css_pbm0lsQQJ7A7WCCIMgxLho6mI_kBNgznNUWmTWcnfoE.css" media="all" />
```

I'd like to serve

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.example.com/sites/default/files/css/css_pbm0lsQQJ7A7WCCIMgxLho6mI_kBNgznNUWmTWcnfoE.css" media="all" />
```

Trying to achieve this in Drupal 6 sites through a module.

Comment: Unless you force a $base_url configuration in the settings.php file, Drupal will always use relative URLs (base URL for both URLs in the question would be `/`... `/about`, `/contact`, likewise).

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Letharion , now the Drupal 6 sites we are maintaining has absolute URLs for Javascript & Stylesheets in headers, and we are using varnish for caching which loads these style sheets and JS files twice, so we are trying to remove the Protocol from the URLs

Comment: Because of how [url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/6) works, relative urls are the default behaviour, so I still have no idea what your trouble is. Why would you need a module, and what would it do?

Comment: @letharion, the op wants to use `//` instead of `http://` or `https://` according to which protocol the user may be browsing. Especially useful in external urls.

Comment: @kekkis Yes exactly which I'm trying to get

Comment: `/about` (Drupal default) is technically the same as `//www.example.com/about` (what you need) protocol wise. Are you trying to serve cookies differently or anything different from the general use case?

Comment: Yes, our content is serving via both https & http, so it is caching twice.Currently both JS and CSS files in header has Full Urls with protocol, so I wanted to remove protocol from Header Style and JS Files.

Comment: But that's exactly the use case for `base_path()`. You don't need the server name at all, just the path relative to your html_root, so to say.

Comment: I edited my question now and I guess it is more clear now and also this issue is resolved and Posted .module implementations in answers and I don't know still why it is in Hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed now. Implemented module_preprocess() (in custom module)

```
function module_name_preprocess(&$vars) {
    foreach (array('head', 'styles', 'scripts') as $replace) {
    if (!isset($vars[$replace])) {
        continue;
    }

    $vars[$replace] = preg_replace('/(src|href|@import )(url\(|=)(")http(s?):/', '$1$2$3', $vars[$replace]);
}
```

}